# Why is my Dell Inspiron 1720's keyboard and trackpad inactive after resume from suspend?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, suspend, inspiron, trackpad

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on my Dell Inspiron 1720 laptop, and it works perfectly apart from coming out of suspend.

The login screen comes up, but the keyboard and trackpad are completely unresponsive. The only option is to hold the power button to do a hard shutdown (pressing it once doesn't bring up the shutdown menu as it normally does).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this or even get more information on what's happening?

Comment: @LuisAlvaredo: There are dozens of similar questions that have not been marked as too localized. Why this one?